# What is the fastest way to switch from one AP to another in Linux

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, networkmanager, wpa-supplicant

I need to switch between APs quickly - in less than 1 second if possible.

Using nmcli or wpa_supplicant the best I can do is about 12 seconds. Does anyone know a method to reduce the time?

Thanks.